# Grunt Task - Get Filename from path without extension

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is it possible to get the filename without the extension from the src filepath.

As an example, let's say the src file is my-file.png - located at images/my-file.png.

In my task I have this at the moment:

```
var processName = options.processName || function (name) { return name; };
var filename = processName(filepath);
```

When I reference `filename` for output it returns:

`images/my-file.png`

I want to only return the actual filename, without the path and without the extension:

`my-file.png`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Might be pretty old but if someone else finds this SO., in reply for @user3143218 's comment :
slice(0, -4) will remove the last 4 characters from the name, so for the example `my-file.png` we will get `my-file` but for `script.js` we will get `scrip`. I suggest using a regex removing everything from the last dot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this:

```
var theFile = filename.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];
var onlyName = theFile.substr(0, theFile.lastIndexOf('.')) || theFile;
```

That should give you `my-file`. The regex gives you the string after the last forward slash, and the next line removes everything after the last dot (and the dot).

Comment: That works well, but i need to also remove the file extension. How could I remove the ".png" part as well?

Comment: actually I used "theFile.slice(0, -4);" Works really well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andeersg's answer below I was able to pull this off. It might not be the best solution but it works. Final code is:

```
var processName = options.processName || function (name) { return name; };
var filename = processName(filepath);
var theFile = filename.match(/\/([^/]*)$/)[1];
var onlyName = theFile.slice(0, -4);
```

Now `onlyName` will return:

`my-file`